# Is 50 minutes enough time to transfer between Terminal A and C at Newark (EWR)?

Tags: short-connections, united-airlines, ewr

We'll be arriving at Newark airport (with two kids under 7) at Terminal A and our flight connection is in Terminal C. Is that enough time to catch the connecting flight?

Update: both flights are on United.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that the minimum connecting time according to the airlines is 40 or 45 minutes between Terminal A & C, so you should be just fine.

If you're flying United, they run a transfer shuttle between Terminals A & C inside security, so you don't have to go through security again.

Answer (score 5):

It depends.  Under normal circumstances I would say yes.  The question though is whether or not you need to collect your luggage which if you are flying United then that won't be a concern but if you travel between the terminals you will have to go through security.  And depending on when your flight is it may be pretty packed.

So once you arrive at terminal A you should go up to the Airtran from Terminal A to Terminal C.  The entire ride takes all of about 3 minutes and trains run every 3-5 minutes at that time you should go down to the security and go through the security checkpoints that are on sides of the terminal I think those are checkpoints 1 and 3.  They are usually less loaded then the central one (2).

Comment: For connection from terminal A to terminal C there is an airside shuttle, so you do not need to clear security or take the airtrain.