# Transiting in Newark from Terminal B to C

Tags: short-connections, united-airlines, ewr

We are a Norwegian family traveling on United from Oslo via Heathrow then Newark to Toronto Pearson. We have almost 90 minutes between the flight from Heathrow landing in Terminal B (20:30) and the flight to Toronto leaving from Terminal C (21:57).

Do we have enough time to catch our flight to Toronto?

Should we have checked in luggage or should we only take handbags in order not to waste time?

What do we have to do in Newark and how long does it usually take?

This will be on a Thursday evening.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. Some past questions of interest include *[What is the connecting time to consider for International to International Transfers in US Airports?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2970)* and *[Transfer time at Newark](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25032)* and especially *[Is 2h 45m enough for a layover in EWR transferring from an int'l to a domestic flight (Terminal B → Terminal C)?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30451)*

Comment: I'm going to vote this as a duplicate as well, as even though the other question deals with an international-to-domestic connection, the answer is the same. There is no exit control in the U.S., and there is no international transit; domestic and international flights often depart from gates right next to each other. So, there is usually little difference in time once you are airside, aside from a handful of high-security routes like Washington to Brussels or New York to Tel Aviv (Newark to Toronto is not one of them).

Answer (score 1):

That may be a very tight fit. You'll need to reclaim your luggage, pass through immigration (if it's packed, it's an easy hour, hour and a half), then bus around or take the air train to C, recheck your luggage and pass through security. If everyone in your party is on the ball and no screaming kids, it might be an easy evolution, but it's possibly to probably going to be a tight fit.