# Time needed for transfer in Newark (US airport), domestic to international

Tags: transit, airports, layovers, ewr

I may be flying from Orlando to Stockholm transferring in Newark, NJ.  How much time would I need to make that transfer?

Comment: One ticket or two? Same airlines or different? Definitely flying USA -> Sweden, or do you need to know about the other direction too?

Comment: related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7775/46

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the connecting time to consider for International to International Transfers in US Airports?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2970/what-is-the-connecting-time-to-consider-for-international-to-international-trans)

Comment: I think this question is different, as it covers the connection from a domestic flight to an international one.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Since I posted this request my travel plans have changed and my question is no longer relevant.

Comment: @JackieRogers You could still update the question with your tentative plan, including airlines and flights, so that the information might be useful to other fellow travellers in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you've not given any real information from which we can assist you, like times, flight numbers, or even airlines. However, for an example, today's arrivals from MCO (Orlando) at or around 4:30ish pm, all come into Terminal C, gate 83. About an hour later, 3 flights depart to ARN (Stockholm) from Terminal C, gate 94. These two gate are about 5-10 minutes walk apart.

How much time you would need for layover to go from one arrival to another departure at any major airport completely depends on a lot of factors, which cannot easily be determined by us. Which Terminals, Gates, what work is occurring on airport grounds, etc, all affect the time it would take you.

Most all major International Airports have available transportation built in to the system (tram, buses or perhaps moving walkways.) Very few should take more than a couple hours, even with immigration, and in most cases, a half hour would be enough, unless you require additional support (wheel chair, children in tow, etc.). Until and unless you can tell us what airlines and times, perhaps flight numbers etc, there is simply no way to get closer.

If I were pressed to present a guess, I'd say 4 hours. :) Because I actually like airports.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on transit through Newark, then you don't need to worry about transfer time. If you are on a point-to-point journey, then you would have to do the following:

1. Deplane
2. Collect your luggage (if any)
3. Check-in for the next flight (so if you have luggage, you'll have to check in that) and get your boarding pass.
4. Go through security

So, schedule enough time to do that.

A cursory check shows the following airlines fly out of Newark to Stockholm:

- SAS - 60 minutes [recommended deadline for check-in](http://www.flysas.com/en/us/travel-info/check-in/check-in-deadlines/)
- United - [60 minutes](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/airport/process/default.aspx)
- Lufthansa - [60 minutes](http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/sa/info_and_services/checkin/checkin_info/!ut/p/c5/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3hnf0PLMI9QZzM_bx8LA0dP19AwIzdLHwtLM6B8JG55I3NidBvgAI4GBHR76Uel5-QnAV0ZDnI3brWuJvjlAwnIg_wBksfjUj-X1LTE0pwS_Uj9KHMcBhn6OpvqR-akpicmV-qH5eUX5QKdXpAbGlEZ7JllEu6oCACqxWoh/dl3/d3/L0lDU0lKSmdra2tra25wQSEvb01vZ0FFSVFoakVJRUpDbE9RUUJqR0NoekFBIS80Q3lqUldfTnIwZ0QyZ3prTEtCeXdnISEvN19DTzE5VkhVQzZOS0w4MEFJRVVWMkY5MU1DNS9xaTdMZTg1NDgwMDAxL3NhLmxBY3Rpb25DaXMvbm9ybWFsL0RlZmF1bHQ!/?l=en&cid=1000350&p=LH&s=SA&l=en&cid=1000350&p=LH&s=SA)

So, its a safe bet you need to arrive at least one hour and 45 minutes before your flight in order to check yourself in for your onward journey.