# Getting from Terminal C to Terminal A in Newark

Tags: united-airlines, short-connections, ewr

I am now freaking out about my 42-minute layover in Newark.  We are arriving at terminal C and have a flight to Quebec 42 minutes later in terminal A.  We do NOT want to have to go through security again. Since United allowed this booking, any chance I can make SURE we get to the next gate/terminal and get on our plane? Fastest Suggestions anyone. Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean 'again', are you past security already ? Are you connecting from another US airport or from abroad ?

Comment: You'll have to go through security again; Newark's design makes this pretty much impossible to avoid. Which makes this connection time very tight, and possibly not doable. But since United allowed this booking, they are responsible for getting you to your destination even if you miss the flight.

Comment: Or I could be wrong and United has a special provision for this transfer. See [Is 50 minutes enough time to transfer between Terminal A and C at Newark (EWR)?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7775/is-50-minutes-enough-time-to-transfer-between-terminal-a-and-c-at-newark-ewr)

Comment: I'm assuming you're connecting from a United domestic flight to a flight to Quebec? There's a shuttle bus inside of security, at least there was a couple months ago and United's [map](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/airport/maps/ewr.aspx) claims it's still there. 42 minutes is tight in that it doesn't give you much room for error if your inbound flight is at all delayed, but it is seemingly within their minimum connection time.